# Building glfw3 programs in CodeBlocks 16.01 in Windows 7 failed

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am using *CodeBlocks 16.01* in Windows7. I have downloaded *GLFW* windows binary [from here](http://www.glfw.org/). I have copied include and `lib-mingw` to my project folder. Have provided the include and `lib-mingw` directories for Compiler and Linker options respectively in the build options. In the Linker settings tab, I have added `glfw3`,`gdi32` and `opengl32`. I'm running the sample program given in the documentation page of the *GLFW* website. The program is compiling. While building a warning and an error message is displayed:

> Warning: .drectve `-aligncomm:"__glfw",5' unrecognized

And

> init.c     undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'

Have googled a lot, but in vain. Any help would be great.

Comment: Consider using Visual Studio as industry standard for Windows

Answer (score 1):

Today the problem is solved. The problem was with the compiler settings in CodeBlocks. In CodeBlocks, under *"Settings"* tab *"Compiler"->"ToolchainExecutables"*, it was *"Dev C++"*. I installed *TDM-GCC-32* (http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) 32 bit version. Then changed *"Dev C++"* with the directory where TDM-GCC-32 is installed in my computer.

Next in *"Settings"->"Debugger"* option, I selected *"GDB/CDB Debugger"* and "Default". Then provided the path of ***gdb32.exe*** located in the *TDM-GCC-32/bin* directory.

I think as I had installed Dev C++ before installing codeblocks, Dev C++ was selected by default (not sure). For those who are facing similar problems but DEV C++ is not their case, updating TDM-GCC may help.

However, this DEV C++ compiler was working for older GLFW 2.7. Today, I have also found another problem with this DEV C++ one. I was using freeglut. When I was including *iostream* along with *GL/glut.h* similar ***"undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'"*** error message was appearing.

But now, it is ok. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to add library(.lib) with this stuff. `.h` file has been 
deployed  already so you need to detect it. Then you can google for library.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for taking out your valuable time. Today the issue has been solved. The problem was with the compiler and debugger settings of codeblocks software. The compiler was set as "Dev C++" maybe because I had Dev C++ installed in my system before installing CodeBlocks. I changed that to TDM-GCC directory and the problem was fixed. However, with that "Dev C++" one I was able to use GLFW 2.7.